# Where can I find mini-nukes in Fallout: New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I would very much like to find mini-nukes in Fallout: New Vegas. I have beaten the game multiple times but have not found any mini-nukes. A little help, please.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at [the Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Mini_nuke_(Fallout:_New_Vegas)#Locations), Mini nukes can be found in the following places:

- Quarry Junction
- Hidden Vally North Bunker
- Camp Searchlight, Searchlight Church Basement
- Nellis Array
- Vault 11
- Nellis Air Force Base
- Nellis Air Force Base mess hall & munitions storage

See the above link for a more detailed description of where they can be found exactly in those locations.  Also, various [commissary terminals](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Commissary_terminal) may sell them, and if you have the *Lonesome Road* add-on, you may also find them rarely in containers and duffle bags.